# subclassing GMSMarker and GMSMapViewDelegate didTapMarker

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

I'm using this simple `MyMarker` class

```
class MyMarker: GMSMarker {
    var id: UInt32 = 0
}
```

so that my markers can also hold an additional numerical tag. When the user taps on my markers I call a `segue` to open a new scene the content's of which are dynamic and drawn with respect to the `MyMarker`'s `id`. I want to do something like:

```
  func mapView(mapView: GMSMapView, didTapMarker marker: MyMarker) -> Bool {
        some_global_variable = marker.id;
        performSegueWithIdentifier("segue", sender: nil)
        return true
    }
```

the problem of course is that the GMSMapViewDelegate expects marker to be of type  `GMSMarker`.

How can I implement the behaviour I am after?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to type cast `GMSMarker` to your custom marker in it's delegate method, don't change signature of `GMSMapViewDelegate` methods.

```
func mapView(mapView: GMSMapView, didTapMarker marker: GMSMarker) -> Bool {
    if let myMarker = marker as? MyMarker {
         some_global_variable = myMarker.id
         performSegueWithIdentifier("segue", sender: nil)
    }
    return true
}
```